# Capturing a conditional, combinational sequence of browser events

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, dom-events

We can listen for and handle single browser events, but how do we listen for a combination of events in sequence?

In pseudocode, we are looking for something like this:

```
element.on('click followed by mouse move', function() {
    // do something
})
```

AFAIK, we can capture just single events at a time. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a simple way using private scope and a simple toggle variable:

```js
(function(){
    // Nothing else can change this, because of it's private scope.
    var clicked = false;
    
    document.getElementById('test').addEventListener('click', function(){
        clicked = clicked ? false : true;
    });
    document.getElementById('test').addEventListener('mousemove', function(){
        if (clicked) {
            console.log('moving while clicked.');
        }
    });
})();
```

```css
#test {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  background-color: #ccf;
}
```

```html
<div id='test'></div>
```